# Is it possible to embed a "Now Playing" Apple Music player tied to my personal Music account on my html website?

Tags: html, apple-music, apple-musickit

This question was previously asked on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/455500/is-it-possible-to-embed-a-now-playing-apple-music-player-tied-to-my-personal-m).

I would like to write a widget which, when my personal Apple Music is currently playing, displays the track name and artist on my website to any visitors. Linking to the track in Music would be nice as well. Is this functionality possible?

(For an example, there is similar functionality with Spotify and Discord, for readers familiar with these programs. By linking your Spotify account to your Discord, your Discord friends can see when you are currently listening to something.)

A [source which I don't 100% trust](https://chat.openai.com) said that it is possible by purchasing an enrollment in the Apple Developer Program, but I don't want to spend $99 a year, and I'm not yet sure it will work if I do. That source gave me a code snippet to try out, but I don't want to spend anything if I don't need to (along with the general healthy distrust that should come when reading its answers).

Are there any alternatives that don't involve using the Apple Developer Program? Preferably free ones.

---

**Update:** some current answers are hesitant to claim this is possible, which is understandable, but there are similar tools out there for other Apple softwares that don’t require access to the API directly and paying for the Apple Developer Program. For instance, see https://open-web-calendar.hosted.quelltext.eu/ which allows you to embed Apple Calendars in html. That’s one reason I remain hopeful.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know its not possible unless you host a server on your pc.

like you said you need the Apple Developer Program for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

I’m sorry to disappoint you but

> this probably won’t work unless you host a server on you’re PC
> like @Waradu said.

Also, there is no alternative to Apple Developer because you can only get information’s from Apple themselves that nobody else has.

Like you said Discord has this feature with Spotify so if you’re interested in that look at the [Spotify  API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/)